# Armadillo sizeof(arma::Mat) gives different results between GCC and NVCC

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, armadillo, nvcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    arma::Mat<float> a;
    cout << sizeof(a) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives different results when I use NVCC for CUDA.

```
$ g++ -o main test.cu.cpp -O3 -larmadillo
$ ./main
112
$ nvcc -o main test.cu.cpp -O3 -larmadillo
$ ./main
104
```

**I wish to make the NVCC version to behave the same as GCC version.**

Where does this difference come from? My project requires compiling different part separately, and since the legacy part must use GCC, converting everything to NVCC is not possible.

**Edit:** here are the compile log between NVCC and GCC, I'm not sure what to look for

```
[huyduc@ny5-dtlgpu06 test]$ nvcc -o main test.cu.cpp -O3 -larmadillo --verbose
#$ _NVVM_BRANCH_=nvvm
#$ _SPACE_= 
#$ _CUDART_=cudart
#$ _HERE_=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin
#$ _THERE_=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=targets/x86_64-linux
#$ TOP=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/..
#$ NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../nvvm/libdevice
#$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../lib:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib64/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/usr/lib:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/usr/local/lib/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mkl/lib:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mkl/mkl/lib/intel64:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mods/libtorch/lib::/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
#$ PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../nvvm/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/bin:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/usr/bin:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mods/libtorch/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/ibutils/bin:/home/huyduc/.local/bin:/home/huyduc/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin
#$ INCLUDES="-I/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"  
#$ LIBRARIES=  "-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs" "-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib"
#$ CUDAFE_FLAGS=
#$ PTXAS_FLAGS=
#$ gcc -c -x c++ -D__NVCC__  -O3 "-I/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"    -D__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=11 -D__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=4 -D__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=100 -D__CUDA_API_VER_MAJOR__=11 -D__CUDA_API_VER_MINOR__=4 -m64 "test.cu.cpp" -o "/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-5_test.cu.o" 
#$ nvlink --arch=sm_52 --register-link-binaries="/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-3_main_dlink.reg.c"  -m64 -larmadillo   "-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs" "-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib" -cpu-arch=X86_64 "/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-5_test.cu.o"  -lcudadevrt  -o "/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-6_main_dlink.sm_52.cubin"
#$ fatbinary -64 -link "--image3=kind=elf,sm=52,file=/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-6_main_dlink.sm_52.cubin" --embedded-fatbin="/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-4_main_dlink.fatbin.c" 
#$ rm /tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-4_main_dlink.fatbin
#$ gcc -c -x c++ -DFATBINFILE="\"/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-4_main_dlink.fatbin.c\"" -DREGISTERLINKBINARYFILE="\"/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-3_main_dlink.reg.c\"" -I. -D__NV_EXTRA_INITIALIZATION= -D__NV_EXTRA_FINALIZATION= -D__CUDA_INCLUDE_COMPILER_INTERNAL_HEADERS__  -O3 "-I/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"    -D__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=11 -D__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=4 -D__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=100 -D__CUDA_API_VER_MAJOR__=11 -D__CUDA_API_VER_MINOR__=4 -m64 "/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/crt/link.stub" -o "/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-7_main_dlink.o" 
#$ g++ -O3 -m64 -Wl,--start-group "/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-7_main_dlink.o" "/tmp/tmpxft_000140a2_00000000-5_test.cu.o" -larmadillo   "-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs" "-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib"  -lcudadevrt  -lcudart_static  -lrt -lpthread  -ldl  -Wl,--end-group -o "main"
```

```
[huyduc@ny5-dtlgpu06 test]$ g++ -o gccc test.cu.cpp -O3 -larmadillo --verbose
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-10.2.0/configure --prefix=/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages --libexecdir=/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-multilib --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-zstd=no
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'gccc' '-O3' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cu.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cu.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test.cu -O3 -version -o /tmp/cctgH2WC.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 10.2.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/usr/include/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mods/libtorch/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/include/
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mods/libtorch/include
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/backward
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 10.2.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: fcab5cdad8fab5c0a9dfd14a10ab3fb4
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'gccc' '-O3' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccPwcVUC.o /tmp/cctgH2WC.s
GNU assembler version 2.36.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1
COMPILER_PATH=/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/../lib64/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib64/../lib64/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib64/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mkl/lib/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mkl/mkl/lib/intel64/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mods/libtorch/lib/:./:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/:/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'gccc' '-O3' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/collect2 -plugin /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccd147SC.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o gccc /lib/../lib64/crt1.o /lib/../lib64/crti.o /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/../lib64 -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib64/../lib64 -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0 -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib64 -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mkl/lib -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mkl/mkl/lib/intel64 -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/mods/libtorch/lib -L. -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../.. /tmp/ccPwcVUC.o -larmadillo -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /local/export/scratch/pulse_packages/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtend.o /lib/../lib64/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'gccc' '-O3' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Comment: nvcc *is* g++ in this case, so run both compilers in verbose mode and check the compiler switches

Comment: What should I look for in `--verbose` output ?

Comment: Look for 32 versus 64 bit pointers, any defines regarding data alignment. Also read any compiler warning that might be emitted.

Comment: I've added the compile log to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wish to make the NVCC version to behave the same as GCC version.

I'm not sure what armadillo version you are using.  I installed 10.8 because it was easy for me to do so. (I am using CUDA 11.4, same as you.) When I run your test case I get sizes that are indeed different between `nvcc` and `g++`, although they don't completely match your sizes, but I also get possibly helpful output from the armadillo developers, did you notice it?

```
$ cat t2106.cpp
#include <iostream>
#ifdef USE_SUGGESTION
#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC
#endif
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    arma::arma_version ver;
    cout << "ARMA version: "<< ver.as_string() << std::endl;

    arma::Mat<float> a;
    cout << sizeof(a) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
$ g++ t2106.cpp -o t2106g++ -larmadillo
$ ./t2106g++
ARMA version: 10.8.2 (Realm Raider)
128
$ nvcc t2106.cpp -o t2106nvcc -larmadillo
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:68:0,
                 from t2106.cpp:5:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:151:106: note: #pragma message: WARNING: this compiler is pretending to be GCC but it may not be fully compatible;
 NG: this compiler is pretending to be GCC but it may not be fully compatible;"

/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:152:110: note: #pragma message: WARNING: to allow this compiler to use GCC features such as data alignment attributes,
 to allow this compiler to use GCC features such as data alignment attributes,"

/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:153:88: note: #pragma message: WARNING: #define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC before #include <armadillo>
 ma message ("WARNING: #define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC before #include <armadillo>"

$ ./t2106nvcc
ARMA version: 10.8.2 (Realm Raider)
112
$ nvcc t2106.cpp -o t2106nvcc -larmadillo -DUSE_SUGGESTION
$ ./t2106nvcc
ARMA version: 10.8.2 (Realm Raider)
128
$
```

So it seems that what the developers have already indicated in 10.8 allows the sizes to be equal in the two cases, which seems to address your question, in so far as your provided test case is concerned.

I don't know what are all the ramifications here, and certainly haven't done any exhaustive testing.  But those sizes appear to be equal with that define present in the code.

> converting everything to NVCC is not possible.

Another alternative would be that you don't have to convert everything to use `nvcc`. Put the armadillo stuff and includes **only** in `.c`/`.cpp` files that are compiled with `gcc` or `g++`, and then use wrapper functions to connect the nvcc compiled files with `gcc` / `g++` compiled files.  In so doing you could avoid this issue entirely without having to use the special `#define`.

Additional discussion:

The relevant object definition is [here](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/11.2.x/include/armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp#L26).  Looking at that code, coupled with the observation of the warning messages, my guess would be that the `arma_aligned` and/or the `arma_aligned_mem` decorators are behaving differently based on compiler detection that the developers have implemented.  But I haven't studied it beyond that.

Comment: Oh, my compiler doesn't show those warning. Anyway, I've found the problem in "usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp". My armadillo version is 7.500.2, which doesn't support the flag `#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC` yet

Comment: So the solution is to edit that file line 156, change it from `#if defined(__GNUG__) && (!defined(ARMA_FAKE_GCC)` to `#if defined(__GNUG__) && (!defined(ARMA_FAKE_GCC) || defined(__NVCC__) || defined(__CUDACC__))`. This solution works with older version of Arma

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works with older version of Armadillo (useful when you can't change legacy code).

The problem is due to these lines in `usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp`, lines 150->156 in Arma 7.500.2 (other versions are different, you can CTRL + F the text `#define ARMA_GOOD_COMPILER` to see near it).

```
#if (defined(__GNUG__) || defined(__GNUC__)) && (defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER) || defined(__NVCC__) || defined(__CUDACC__) || defined(__PGI) || defined(__PATHSCALE__) || defined(__ARMCC_VERSION) || defined(__IBMCPP__))
  #undef  ARMA_FAKE_GCC
  #define ARMA_FAKE_GCC
#endif


#if defined(__GNUG__) && !defined(ARMA_FAKE_GCC)
... define arma_aligned and arma_align_mem here
#endif
```

New versions have a flag `#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC` that disable checking for `ARMA_FAKE_GCC`, so it works with CUDA. But since old versions don't have it, you have to add it yourself by editing `/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp` (this path might differ between PCs)

```
#if defined(__GNUG__) && (!defined(ARMA_FAKE_GCC) || defined(__NVCC__) || defined(__CUDACC__))
... define arma_aligned and arma_align_mem here
#endif
```

Example program to test the difference below. On my machine with Arma 7.500.2, `nvcc` gives 104 before the change, and 112 after (same as `g++`). Also, before the change, `arma_aligned` and `arma_align_mem` is undefined (empty string), while after they become `__attribute__((__aligned__))` and `__attribute__((__aligned__(16)))` (again, same as g++).

```
#include <iostream>
#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC
#define ARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_CLANG
#include <armadillo>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFYMACRO(y) STRINGIFY(y)

int main()
{
    arma::arma_version ver;
        std::cout << "ARMA version: "<< ver.as_string() << std::endl;
    
    arma::Mat<float> a;
    cout << sizeof(a) << "\n";
    
    cout << STRINGIFYMACRO(arma_aligned) << "\n";
    cout << STRINGIFYMACRO(arma_align_mem) << "\n";    

    return 0;
}
```